# Change default global tint color in swift

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, ios8, xcode6

I'm developing a little app and I would like to change the default global tint color from blue to orange. I've seen many ways to do it in Objective-C but I can't seem to get it to work using swift. How could I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

*This answer was last revised for Swift 5.2 and iOS 13.5 SDK.*

---

You can set the [`tintColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622467-tintcolor) on your window. Because tint color cascades down to all subviews (unless explicitly overridden), setting it on a window will effectively make it global inside that window.

Add the following line to your [`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application) or [`scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3197914-scene) just before making the window key and visible:

```swift
window.tintColor = .systemOrange /* or .orange on iOS < 13 */
```

You can also set in in the storyboard by changing the `Global Tint` property:

[image]

Comment: When I add the code you provided me, the view doesn't load and this shows up in the console: "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Yes! It's sooooo easy I don't know how I couldn't come up with this earlier. Thanks for the answer! :D EDIT: I've set it there but the color isn't changing o.o

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure you aren't overriding this color? Maybe implicitly in some other IB files?

Comment: In case it is needed, you can check the code here: https://github.com/jmml97/Pocket-Money/tree/master

Comment: It works! Try adding a stepper or a slider... If you wanted to change the tab bar items' highlight color, you have to do that explicitly, they don't respond to the `tintColor`. Also, labels have their own `textColor` property too.

Comment: Oh, yeah that's what I wanted. I thought that the tint color also changed the highlight color (which would be logical). So, do you know how to do it? Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58546/discussion-between-jose-maria-and-akashivskyy).

Comment: Hi, I know this is old, but maybe someone has the answer to how to change the tab bar items' highlight color in swift 3 now? Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

A small update from Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/setting_the_app_s_tint_color). Tested with Xcode Version 12.4.

There is now an `AccentColor` in the Color Asset catalogue which can be set in the build settings. In newer projects it is set by default but older projects might need to add it manually.

1. Create a Color Asset with the name "`AccentColor`" (or whatever you like)
   [image]
2. Go to your Build Settings of your Target and add the name of your color asset as the value for the entry "`Global Accent Color Name`".
   [image]

> **Note** that `AccentColor` asset-name is NOT a preserved keyword, and can be anything custom, but the Build setting is what makes this work.
>
> Basically, `iOS` has nothing equal to the `Android` theme yet (2021), where standard colors have keywords, and we can not simply set those in assets.

Comment: Actual best solution. Didn't know that was a thing, pretty amazing.

Comment: It's also cool that you can access it with `UIColor(named:"AccentColor")`, too, which helps when establishing a uniform theme in the app.

Comment: Is there any way to dynamically change this, where you are able to change the colour inapp, without having to rebuild through Xcode?

I currently save the user selected colour to userDefaults and set the window?.tintColor inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, but obviously this will only change when the app is relaunched.

Comment: I doubt it since the assets are all static. I also did not stumble upon any other way than the one you described.