# How to set screen tint color Cocoa mac app

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, screen

I'd like to create a Mac App that will tint the whole screen (not just one window). This would behave like [flux](https://justgetflux.com/) for those that are familiar.

I am unsure of how to access the view that is the whole screen on the mac. Ideally I'd be able to so something like `NSScreen.main.tintColor = NSColor.orange` but I don't know how to do this for a Mac App.

Comment: What do you mean by the whole screen?  What do you mean by not just one window but the whole screen?  What's the relationship between a window of your application or whatever and whatever you mean by the whole screen?

Comment: I think this link might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094976/change-default-global-tint-color-in-swift

Comment: Duplicate of [Swift cocoa - How to color overlay full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946217/swift-cocoa-how-to-color-overlay-full-screen)